# errors compiling rgbdslam, g2o errors about cholmod

Tags: slam, navigation, g2o, ubuntu, ubuntu-oneiric

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello!  I am trying to build rgbdslam and not having much luck.  I am using Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit.  I have latest ros electric installed.  I pulled the latest rgbdslam (from [http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/~endres/rgbdslam/rgbdslam.tgz](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Eendres/rgbdslam/rgbdslam.tgz)).  I also pulled g2o from svn.  g2o builds fine and all dependencies pulled down and built when I did a "rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam".  Initially I was getting some errors related to undefined references and it appeared that the g2o libs were not being linked in.  So I added all the libg2o* libraries to rgbdslam's CMakeLists.txt.  This got me further but some errors remain and I'm not sure where these dependencies are.

Here is an excerpt from my buildfailures-with-context.txt:

```
[ 29%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/rgbdslam/build'
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/rgbdslam/build'
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/rgbdslam/build'
Linking CXX executable ../bin/rgbdslam
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `LinearSolverCholmod':
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:75: undefined reference to `cholmod_start'
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:75: undefined reference to `cholmod_start'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> >::init()':
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:98: undefined reference to `cholmod_free_factor'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `~LinearSolverCholmod':
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:89: undefined reference to `cholmod_free_factor'
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:92: undefined reference to `cholmod_finish'
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:89: undefined reference to `cholmod_free_factor'
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:92: undefined reference to `cholmod_finish'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> >::computeSymbolicDecomposition(g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> > const&)':
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:252: undefined reference to `cholmod_analyze'
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:278: undefined reference to `cholmod_amd'
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:301: undefined reference to `cholmod_analyze_p'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> >::solvePattern(g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1, 0, -1, -1> >&, std::vector<std::pair<int, int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int, int> > > const&, g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> > const&)':
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:202: undefined reference to `cholmod_factorize'
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:207: undefined reference to `cholmod_change_factor'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> >::solve(g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> > const&, double*, double*)':
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:123: undefined reference to `cholmod_factorize'
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:130: undefined reference to `cholmod_solve'
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:132: undefined reference to `cholmod_free_dense'
CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/src/graph_manager.o: In function `g2o::LinearSolverCholmod<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> >::solveBlocks(double**&, g2o::SparseBlockMatrix<Eigen::Matrix<double, 6, 6, 0, 6, 6> > const&)':
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:162: undefined reference to `cholmod_factorize'
/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/g2o/include/g2o/solvers/cholmod/linear_solver_cholmod.h:167: undefined reference to `cholmod_change_factor'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [../bin/rgbdslam] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/rgbdslam/build'
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/rgbdslam.dir/all] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/rgbdslam/build'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jpeverill/.ros/localstacks/rgbdslam/build'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Any ideas?  My configuration does not seem unusual so I'm not sure why I'm having issues.  Most of the troubleshooting online appears to be related to a previous version of rgbdslam which used hogman_minimal instead of g2o.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12645/errors-compiling-rgbdslam,-g2o-errors-about-cholmod/) by [arsenix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1651/arsenix/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2012-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok I think I fixed this one.  Didn't realize cholmod was an external library called by g2o/eigen.

I changed the following line in the CMakeLists.txt to add the cholmod library and all the g2o libs to the rgbdslam build:
SET(LIBS_LINK rgbdslam GL GLU cholmod g2o_cli g2o_core g2o_incremental g2o_interactive g2o_interface g2o_math_groups g2o_parser g2o_solver_cholmod g2o_solver_csparse g2o_solver_dense g2o_solver_pcg g2o_stuff g2o_types_icp g2o_types_sba g2o_types_sim3 g2o_types_slam2d g2o_types_slam3d ${QT_LIBRARIES} ${QT_QTOPENGL_LIBRARY} ${GLUT_LIBRARY} ${OPENGL_LIBRARY} ${OpenCV_LIBS})

With this addition it builds... now on to the next challenge :)

---

Originally posted by [arsenix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1651/arsenix/) with karma: 66 on 2012-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-01-16**:
Well done. This problem occured to me too last week after upgrading from ubu 11.04 to 11.10. If you have further problems let me know. I updated the google code repository (see http://ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam) with the latest Version of rgbdslam. It hasn't been thoroughly tested though.